# Emacs can't find plink

Tags: emacs, tramp

I am running emacs 24 and I want to set up tramp to read/write file on my ubuntu machine.

I read [emacs 24 on windows 7, tramp cannot find plink program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14272107/emacs-24-on-windows-7-tramp-cannot-find-plink-program). And i did print the exec path, I do have C:/Programs/Putty in my exec path:

```
exec-path is a variable defined in `C source code'.
Its value is
("C:/Programs/PuTTy" .....)
```

But I still get

```
plink -load 10.136.11.77 -t env 'TERM=dumb' 'PROMPT_COMMAND=' 'PS1=#$ ' /bin/sh && exit || exit
plink is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I have this in my .emacs:

```
(require 'tramp)

(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/") t)


(add-to-list 'exec-path "C:/Programs/PuTTy")
(if (eq system-type 'windows-nt)
    (setq tramp-default-method "plinkx"))
```

any idea how to fix my problem?

Comment: Just guessing, is `plink` in your `PATH`? Start `ielm` (`M-x ielm`) and execute `(getenv "PATH")`

Comment: Yes, I see it , I see C:\\Programs\\PuTTY when I do (getenv "PATH")

Comment: When I open a console, i type 'plink' it said "recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file." But ifI do 'plink.exe.' it prints out help. What should I do to make tramp to use plink.exe instead?

Comment: HI - I am trying to get this working and still get an issue. My .emacs is as yours, path to putty updated tho, and I get the following error: 'ssh' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.